# Setting a permanent static route with DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp

I am trying to set up a machine on a local network that uses a permanent gateway and DHCP. I can't set the IP static, but need to add the route inserting the gateway. When I try a "route add" command, it tells me the operation is not permitted. Trying to enter it in the GUI box for the network adapter never gives me the option to say "OK"

Thanks for any assistance.

I'm adding in the stuff I tried which should make for an entertaining read to those who do this all the time.  But, we all started somewhere :)

Here is what I'm getting:

```
XXXXX@S08:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo route add 10.0.0.3
SIOCADDRT: No such device

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 10.0.0.3
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0 gw 10.0.0.3
SIOCADDRT: Invalid argument

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo route add -net gw 10.0.0.3
gw: Host name lookup failure

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo ip route add 10.0.0.3
RTNETLINK answers: No such device

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo ip route add 10.0.0.3 eth0
Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "eth0" is a garbage.

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo inet_route add gw 10.0.0.3
sudo: inet_route: command not found

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo ip route add eth0
Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "eth0".

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo ip route add 10.0.0.3
RTNETLINK answers: No such device

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo ip -d addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.3
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.3 eth0
SIOCADDRT: No such device

XXXXX@S08:~$ sudo ip route add 10.0.0.3 dev eth0
Cannot find device "eth0"
```

So there you have it -

Comment: Try `sudo route add xxx` or the more modern `sudo ip route add xxx`.

Comment: I was using the sudo command line, but it seems no matter what I type it doesn't like it. What I'm attempting to do is find a place I can insert a permanent gateway so I have outside (internet) access to move forward on the install.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `route -n` (or `ip route`) and the exact command that you use to add the route, as well as its output? Please edit the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continued searching and grief, I found that the onboard network card was not supported.  I disabled it and installed an aftermarket card and was able to add the route without a problem.
The command I used was:

```
# route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx eth0
```